# Get unicode block element based on matrix

Tags: matrix, unicode

A unique question I guess, given these unciode block elements:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements

I want to get the relevant block element based on the matrix I get, so
11
01 will give ▜

00
10 will give ▖

and so on

I managed to do this in python, but I wonder if anyone got a more elegant solution.

```py
from itertools import product

elements = [0, 1]
a = product(elements, repeat=2)
b = product(a, repeat=2)
matrices = [c for c in b]

"""
Matrices generated possiblities
00 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11
00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11 00 01 11 10 00 01 10 11
"""

blocks = [' ', '▗', '▖', '▄', '▝', '▐', '▞', '▟', '▘', '▚', '▙', '▌', '▀', '▜', '▛', '█']

given = (
    (0,1),
    (1,0)
)

print(blocks[matrices.index(given)])

output: ▞
```

Answer (score 1):

These characters, although existing, were not meant to have a direct correlation
of numbers-to-set-1/4 blocks.

So, I have a solution in a published package, and it is not necessarily
more "elegant" than yours, as it is far more verbose.

However, the code around it allows one to "draw" on a text terminal
using these 1/4 blocks as pixels, in a somewhat clean API.

So, [this is the class](https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/55f830e714208c978f36adc117c56804f8e92706/terminedia.py#L204) I use to set/reset pixels in a character block. The relevant methods can be used straight from the class, and they take the"pixel coordinates", and the current character block upon which to set or reset the addressed pixel. The code instantiates the class just to be able to use the `in` operator to check for block-characters.

The project can be installed with "pip install terminedia".

The function and class bellow, extracted from the project, will work in standalone to do the same as you do:

```py
# Snippets from jsbueno/terminedia, v. 0.2.0

def _mirror_dict(dct):
    """Creates a new dictionary exchanging values for keys
    Args:
      - dct (mapping): Dictionary to be inverted
    """
    return {value: key for key, value in dct.items()}


class BlockChars_:
    """Used internaly to emulate pixel setting/resetting/reading inside 1/4 block characters

    Contains a listing and other mappings of all block characters used in order, so that
    bits in numbers from 0 to 15 will match the "pixels" on the corresponding block character.

    Although this class is purposed for internal use in the emulation of
    a higher resolution canvas, its functions can be used by any application
    that decides to manipulate block chars.

    The class itself is stateless, and it is used as a single-instance which
    uses the name :any:`BlockChars`. The instance is needed so that one can use the operator
    ``in`` to check if a character is a block-character.

    """
    EMPTY = " "
    QUADRANT_UPPER_LEFT = '\u2598'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_RIGHT = '\u259D'
    UPPER_HALF_BLOCK = '\u2580'
    QUADRANT_LOWER_LEFT = '\u2596'
    LEFT_HALF_BLOCK = '\u258C'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_RIGHT_AND_LOWER_LEFT = '\u259E'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_LEFT_AND_UPPER_RIGHT_AND_LOWER_LEFT = '\u259B'
    QUADRANT_LOWER_RIGHT = '\u2597'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_LEFT_AND_LOWER_RIGHT = '\u259A'
    RIGHT_HALF_BLOCK = '\u2590'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_LEFT_AND_UPPER_RIGHT_AND_LOWER_RIGHT = '\u259C'
    LOWER_HALF_BLOCK = '\u2584'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_LEFT_AND_LOWER_LEFT_AND_LOWER_RIGHT = '\u2599'
    QUADRANT_UPPER_RIGHT_AND_LOWER_LEFT_AND_LOWER_RIGHT = '\u259F'
    FULL_BLOCK = '\u2588'

    # This depends on Python 3.6+ ordered behavior for local namespaces and dicts:
    block_chars_by_name = {key: value for key, value in locals().items() if key.isupper()}
    block_chars_to_name = _mirror_dict(block_chars_by_name)
    blocks_in_order = {i: value for i, value in enumerate(block_chars_by_name.values())}
    block_to_order = _mirror_dict(blocks_in_order)

    def __contains__(self, char):
        """True if a char is a "pixel representing" block char"""
        return char in self.block_chars_to_name

    @classmethod
    def _op(cls, pos, data, operation):
        number = cls.block_to_order[data]
        index = 2 ** (pos[0] + 2 * pos[1])
        return operation(number, index)

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, pos, data):
        """"Sets" a pixel in a block character

        Args:
          - pos (2-sequence): coordinate of the pixel inside the character
            (0,0) is top-left corner, (1,1) bottom-right corner and so on)
          - data: initial character to be composed with the bit to be set. Use
            space ("\x20") to start with an empty block.

        """
        op = lambda n, index: n | index
        return cls.blocks_in_order[cls._op(pos, data, op)]

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls, pos, data):
        """"resets" a pixel in a block character

        Args:
          - pos (2-sequence): coordinate of the pixel inside the character
            (0,0) is top-left corner, (1,1) bottom-right corner and so on)
          - data: initial character to be composed with the bit to be reset.
        """
        op = lambda n, index: n & (0xf - index)
        return cls.blocks_in_order[cls._op(pos, data, op)]

    @classmethod
    def get_at(cls, pos, data):
        """Retrieves whether a pixel in a block character is set

        Args:
          - pos (2-sequence): The pixel coordinate
          - data (character): The character were to look at blocks.

        Raises KeyError if an invalid character is passed in "data".
        """
        op = lambda n, index: bool(n & index)
        return cls._op(pos, data, op)


#: :any:`BlockChars_` single instance: enables ``__contains__``:
BlockChars = BlockChars_()
```

After pasting only this in the terminal it is possible to do:

```py
In [131]: pixels = BlockChars.set((0,0), " ")                                                                     

In [132]: print(BlockChars.set((1,1), pixels))     

# And this internal "side-product" is closer to what you have posted:

In [133]: BlockChars.blocks_in_order[0b1111]                                                                      
Out[133]: '█'

In [134]: BlockChars.blocks_in_order[0b1010]                                                                      
Out[134]: '▐'
```

The project at https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia have a complete
drawing API do use these as pixels in an ANSI text terminal - 
including bezier curves, filled ellipses, and RGB image display
(check the "examples" folder)

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out, my idea was the same, to be used for printing QR codes

Comment: I think there is not a straightforward way to get the "image" back from the buffer I use there - it prints to the terminal. But it is easy enough to add such a call - I will try to do that later today and tell you here.